# Python prefect skip task if others failed

Tags: prefect

I have two tasks A and B in my workflow and I want to skip B if task failed,any idea please?
@task
A():
Pass
B():
Pass
Flow("") as flow:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefect's default behavior is not to run task B if upstream task A fails. But those tasks must depend on each other either explicitly via the `upstream_tasks` keyword or implicitly by passing data between each other. You can also use [triggers](https://docs.prefect.io/core/about_prefect/next-steps.html#triggers) to control this behavior.

Example of how you can set dependencies:

```py
from prefect import task, Flow

@task
def task_1():
    pass

@task
def task_2():
    pass

@task
def task_3():
    pass

with Flow("flow_with_dependencies") as flow:
    t1 = task_1()
    t2 = task_2(upstream_tasks=[t1])
    t3 = task_3(upstream_tasks=[t2])
```

Comment: Prefect v2 is different.